# Se clicar no ID exibido, ele abre uma outra página com um formulario pré preenchido com as informações

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde a todos! Sou iniciante na programação WEB e estou com uma grande duvida, criei um formulário anterior onde a pessoa digita os dados e é salvo no banco de dados, criei também uma outra tela onde exibe todos os resultados em uma tabela, agora nessa tela onde está dentro de uma tabela, queria colocar que quando clicado em cima do ID, ele abre o formulário novamente com as informações do ID clicado já preenchidos. Por favor, se puderem me ajudar serei muito grato. Os códigos são:

OBS: Não estou pedindo para montarem para mim, quero apenas alguma dica de como posso fazer isso, estou pesquisando mas não estou entendendo muito bem, obrigado!

FORMULARIO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ficha de cadastro</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validar_form(){
            var nome = formcontato.nome.value;
            var snome = formcontato.snome.value;
            var datanasc = formcontato.datanasc.value;
            var endereco = formcontato.endereco.value;
            var numero = formcontato.numero.value;
            var bairro = formcontato.bairro.value;
            var telefone = formcontato.telefone.value;


            if (nome == "") {
                alert("campo nome é obrigatório");
                formcontato.nome.focus();
                return false;
            }if (snome == "") {
                alert("campo sobrenome é obrigatório");
                formcontato.snome.focus();
                return false;
            }if (datanasc == "") {
                alert("campo data de nascimento é obrigatório");
                formcontato.datanasc.focus();
                return false;
            }if (endereco == "") {
                alert("campo de endereço é obrigatório");
                formcontato.endereco.focus();
                return false;
            }if (numero == "") {
                alert("campo de numero é obrigatório");
                formcontato.numero.focus();
                return false;
            }if (bairro == "") {
                alert("campo de bairro é obrigatório");
                formcontato.bairro.focus();
                return false;
            }if (telefone == "") {
                alert("campo nome é obrigatório");
                formcontato.telefone.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- -->
<form name="formcontato" action="dadoscliente.php" id="form" method="POST" >
    <table border="1" align="center">

        <h1 align="center">Ficha de cadastro</h1>

        <tr><td>Nome: <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" id="nome" name="nome" ></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Sobrenome: <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu sobrenome" id="snome" name="snome"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Estado Civil: 
            <select name="estadociv">
                <option>Solteiro</option>
                <option>Casado</option>
                <option>Divorciado</option>
            </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Data de nascimento: <input type="date" id="datanasc" name="datanasc"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Endereco: <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu endereço" id="endereco" name="endereco"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Numero: <input type="number" placeholder="Digite o numero da casa" id="numero" name="numero"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Bairro: <input type="text" id="bairro" placeholder="Digite o bairro" name="bairro"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Estado: 
            <select name="estado">
                <option>Sao Paulo</option>
                <option>Rio de Janeiro</option>
                <option>Santa Catarina</option>
            </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Telefone: <input type="tel" id="telefone" placeholder="(xx) xxxx-xxxx" name="telefone"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="return validar_form()" id="enviar"></td></tr>


    </table>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

TABELA COM OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS:

```php
<?php 

    session_start();
    include_once('conexao.php');
 ?>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <style type="text/css">

table, th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
}

}
table {
border-spacing: 15px;
}

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<form>
    
    <table style="width: 100">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Estado civil</th>
                <th>Data de nascimento</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php

                $result_usuarios = " SELECT * FROM teste.cadastro";
                $resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuarios);
                while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuarios)){
                    echo 
                        "<tr>
                            <td><a href='http://127.0.0.1/teste/'>".$row_usuario["codigo"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["nome"]. "</a></td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["sobrenome"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["estadociv"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["datanasc"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario['endereco'] . ", " . $row_usuario['numero'] . " - " . $row_usuario['bairro'] . "</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["estado"]."</td>
                            <td>".$row_usuario["telefone"]."</td>
                        </tr>";

            
                }
            ?>  


        </tbody>


    </table>

</form>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: faz  a página "teste" que tem na tua url ler (pode ser request da url por exemplo) o ID, faz o mesmo `select`, mas com `where` com o id e retorna esses dados

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, consegui colocar o ID pela URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você fez boa parte do caminho. Uma das forma mais usadas é você enviar o ID via `$_GET`, e recuperar os dados na outra tela, no seu caso a tela de formulário. Seu link ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<td><a href=http://127.0.0.1/teste/formulario.php?codigo=".$row_usuario["codigo"].">".$row_usuario["codigo"]."</td>
```

Ou assim se estiver usando url amigáveis

```
<td><a href='http://127.0.0.1/teste/".$row_usuario["codigo"]."/>".$row_usuario["codigo"]."</td>
```

Na sua página página com o formulário você recupera os dados normalmente com uma consulta no banco.

```
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
$result_usuarios = " SELECT * FROM teste.cadastro WHERE codigo='{$codigo}'";
$resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($con, $result_usuarios);
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuarios);

<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['nome']; ">
```

**EDIT**

Neste caso você não vai precisar do `while` pois estará retornando apenas um registros, isso se seu campo código for um ID único na sua base de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui fazer dar certo!